# can't get height of popover content div with forward ref's current

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ref

i can't figure it out so after a long quest of searching the web, i'm still don get it, so i'll try here:

so, i'v got a **Popover** functional component (with the red border) that holds an element, and a **PopoverContent** component that shows the popup itself (the gold border in the pic).

what i need is to get the height of the **PopoverContent** so i can use this number to calculate it's location on the screen according to the **Popover** element itself.

it's more accurate to say that i'm trying to implement a **Portal** option for the **PopoverContent** so it can be viewed without be cutting by a parent component higher on the DOM hirarchy.

The **Popover.tsx** component looks like so:

```
const Popover = (props: React.PropsWithChildren<PopoverProps>) => {
  const {
    translateX,
    translateY,
    style,
    children,
    contentComponent,
    isDisabled,
    contentPosition,
    isOpenFromOutside,
    onClick = () => null,
    onIsOpenChanged = () => null,
    onClickOutside,
    offset,
    isSide,
    className,
    isVisible = true,
    asPortal,
    coords = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    }
  } = props;

  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [popoverWidth, setPopoverWidth] = useState(0);
  const [popoverHeight, setPopoverHeight] = useState(0);
  const [popoverCoords, setPopoverCoords] = useState(coords); // takes current popover popoverCoords
  const popoverRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const contentRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsOpen(isOpenFromOutside!);
  }, [isOpenFromOutside]);

  useEffect(() => {
    onIsOpenChanged(isOpen);
  }, [isOpen]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (popoverRef.current) {
      const rect = popoverRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
      setPopoverCoords({
        top: rect.left,
        right: rect.right,
        bottom: rect.bottom,
        left: rect.top
      });
      setPopoverWidth(popoverRef.current.offsetWidth);
      setPopoverHeight(popoverRef.current.offsetHeight);
    }
  }, [popoverRef]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("%c popover contentRef ", "background: green; color: #fff", contentRef);
  }, [contentRef]);

  useOnClickOutside(popoverRef, contentRef, () => {
    if (onClickOutside) {
      return onClickOutside();
    }

    setIsOpen(false);
  });

  const handleClick = async (e: any) => {
    if (isDisabled || !isVisible) return;

    await onClick(e);
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  const renderContent = () => (
    <PopoverContent
      className="popover-content"
      translateX={translateX}
      translateY={translateY}
      isSide={isSide}
      contentPosition={contentPosition}
      ref={contentRef}
      onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}
      popoverWidth={popoverWidth}
      popoverHeight={popoverHeight}
      offset={offset}
      coords={popoverCoords}
      isVisible={isVisible}>
      {contentComponent}
    </PopoverContent>
  );

  const renderPopoverContent = () => {
    if (!isOpen) return null;

    if (asPortal) return <Portal>{renderContent()}</Portal>;

    return renderContent();
  };

  return (
    <PopoverWrapper
      {...{ translateX, translateY, style, isVisible }}
      data-automation-id={props["data-automation-id"]}
      onClick={handleClick}
      className={`popover-wrapper ${className}`}
      ref={popoverRef}>
      {children}
      {isVisible && renderPopoverContent()}
    </PopoverWrapper>
  );
};

export default Popover;
```

And here is the **PopoverContent.tsx** component code :

```
type ReactPopoverProps = React.PropsWithChildren<PopoverProps>;

const PopoverContent = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, ReactPopoverProps>((props, ref) => {
  const {
    coords,
    translateX,
    translateY,
    isSide,
    contentPosition,
    children,
    style,
    popoverWidth,
    popoverHeight,
    offset = sizeType.xSmall,
    onClick
  } = props;

  // const [contentWidth, setContentWidth] = useState<number>(0);
  const [contentHeight, setContentHeight] = useState<number>(0);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);

  // const div = document.createElement("div");
  const myRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("%c my lcontent myRef ", "background: blue; color: #fff", myRef);
    if (myRef && myRef.current) {
      const rect = myRef.current?.getBoundingClientRect()
      console.log('ref height', rect)
      setHeight(rect.height)
    }
  }, [myRef]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('%c local height ', 'background: yellow; color: #fff', height);
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("%c ref > ", "background: red; color: #fff", ref);
    if (ref && ref.current) {
      console.log("%c ref > ", "background: red; color: #fff", ref);
    }
  });

  return (
    <ContentWrapper
      {...{ coords, translateX, translateY, isSide }}
      {...{ style, offset, contentPosition, popoverWidth, popoverHeight }}
      ref={ref}
      {...{ contentHeight, onClick }}>
      {children}
    </ContentWrapper>
  );
});

export default PopoverContent;
```

how can i get the **height** of the **Popover** itself?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYNkk.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using the ref itself as a dependency on the `useEffect` will trigger a re-run. In addition, I assume the `useEffect` runs before the content is rendered, therefore not giving you the correct size. What I would rather do is to use a [ReziseObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver).

You'll then be able to get both the correct height and the width of the popup everytime its size changes, something along these lines:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (popoverRef.current) {
      const observer = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
        setPopoverCoords({
          top: entries[0].contentRect.left,
          right: entries[0].contentRect.right,
          bottom: entries[0].contentRect.bottom,
          left: entries[0].contentRect.top
        });
      });
      popoverRef && observer.observe(popoverRef.current);
      return () => {
        popoverRef && observer.unobserve(popoverRef.current);
      };
    }
  }, []);
```